# How to reduce transaction propagation time

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, enode, transaction-propagation

I want to reduce the propagation time of my transactions to the minimum (ie. the time it takes for my transactions to reach miners). My transactions are broadcasted on my local Geth node (full node). I already have excellent hardware and internet connection speed.

1. **I understand that increasing the number of peers my node is connected to should reduce propagation time, but is there an optimal amount of peers to be connected to?**
2. **Is it possible to find the enode address of miners so that I can connect to them directly (static peers)?**

I know that it is possible to reduce the propagation time further because I observe transactions that reach miners before mine even if they were sent at the same time.

Comment: For point 1: do you mean increase the number of connected peers or the number of peers only (in the network). If the number of peers only, more target to reach, more time to propagate.

Comment: I meant connected peers. I will edit.